# mui styles not compatible with react version 18

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here are my dependencies

```
"name": "get_it_done",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.134",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.6",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.13.2",
    "@mui/system": "^5.13.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.28.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.2"
  },
```

The app is running perfectly on local system but when I try to host it on vercel or netlify I am having issue as follow :

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/styles@5.13.2 npm ERR! Found:
> react@18.2.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0"
> from the root project npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from
> @emotion/react@11.11.1 npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react npm ERR!
> @emotion/react@"^11.11.1" from the root project npm ERR!     peer
> @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@emotion/styled npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.11.0"
> from the root project npm ERR!       4 more (@mui/lab, @mui/material,
> @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system) npm ERR!     4 more (@mui/lab,
> @mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system) npm ERR!   18 more
> (@emotion/styled, ...) npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not resolve
> dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.13.2 npm
> ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"^5.13.2" from
> the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency:
> react@17.0.2 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   peer
> react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.13.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@mui/styles npm ERR!     @mui/styles@"^5.13.2" from the
> root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict,
> or retry npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm
> ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
> resolution. npm ERR!  npm ERR!  npm ERR! For a full report see: npm
> ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-07-01T11_25_44_295Z-eresolve-report.txt
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-07-01T11_25_44_295Z-debug-0.log Error: Command
> "npm install" exited with 1 BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm install"
> exited with 1

I tried installing latest versions of mui as well and deleting and installing node modules again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mui/styles v5 is not compatible with React V18. If you wanna use @mui/styles, you have to downgrade your react version to v17 or lower.

Comment: MUI v5 is compatible with React 18, just not @mui/styles which is a deprecated package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).